# Cannot press button with VBA

Tags: vba, button, html

I want to press a button on a webpage through VBA, using Internet Explorer.
I do it for several webpages without problems, but I cannot do it for a particular one.

The HTML code of the button is

```
<button type="submit" name="submitImportFile" id="submitImportFile" class="btn btn-default pull-right" >
<i class="process-icon-next"></i>
<span>Pasul următor</span>
</button>
```

How can I press it using VBA?

I tried

```
Set allhyperlinks = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("button")
        For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
            If hyper_link.getattribute("name") = "submitImportFile" Then
                hyper_link.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

...and it's not working.
Thanks!

I figured out that the code is wotking very well when run from a different computer.
But when I run it from my desktop, I get the error "Object required" at line

```
ie.Document.getElementById("import").Click
```

Why could be wrong? I checked the VBA refferences, they are the same on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `.GetAttribute` call.

```
For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
      If hyper_link.Name = "submitImportFile" Then
           hyper_link.Click
           Exit For
      End If
Next hyper_link
```

That should be sufficient for checking the `.Name` of an element. Remember that VBA is by default case sensitive. Is there a reason you are not using the following?

`IE.Document.getElementById("submitImportFile").Click`

Comment: Yesterday your solution worked, today it's not working anymore. I just don't get it. The button is pressed, but the page remains the same. If I press the button with the mouse, then it works!

Comment: I cannot really speak as to why the button is not processing the call but it appear to be clicking. Personally, I avoid the `<button>.Click` method in favor of something more like `IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("form")(0).submit`.